# Passing data properties in vue js laravel component

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2

Am new to Vue.js and I would like to pass the data propert value to my template.

I have:

```
export default {
  name: "profile",
  data: () => ({
    user:[]
  }),
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('/api/user')
      .then(function (response) {
        this.user = response
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
        console.error(response);
      });
  }
}
```

In the HTML template I have:

```
<template>
  <div>{{user.name }}</div>
</template>
```

Now I am getting an error of

> cannot set property `user` of `undefined`

A `console.log(response)` produces:

> name: "user 1", // name exists
>   email ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `arrow function` for axios callbacks

```
.then((response) => {
    this.user = response
})
```

`arrow function` binds the components context as you expect.

Comment: Thanks, this works,   also i had to make a few changes ive realized that response i needed to use this.user=response.data

Answer (score 0):

In mounted:

```
mounted() {
    var self = this;
    axios.get('/api/user')
        .then(function (response) {
           self.user = response
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
           console.error(response);
        });
     }
}
```